# Oracle split rows into multiple rows based on column value

Tags: sql, oracle

I need an advice on how to achieve the following.

I have a table similar to this one :

```
WITH CTE ( slno, column1, column2, column3, slno2, column4, column5, column6, column7, column8, column9, column10, column11 ) AS (
  SELECT 10000, 'a', 'aa', ';', 10000, 'aaa', 'aaaa', 'aaaaa','aaaaaa', ';', 'aaaaa2', 'aaaaa12', 'aaaa22' FROM DUAL UNION 
  SELECT 10001, 'b', 'bb', ';', 10001, 'bbb', 'bbbb', 'bbbb', 'bbbbbb', ';', 'bbbbb2', 'bbbbb12', 'bbb22'  FROM DUAL UNION 
  SELECT 10001, 'c', 'cc', ';', 10001, 'ccc', 'cccc', 'cccc', 'cccccc', ';', 'ccccc2', 'ccccc12', 'ccc22'  FROM DUAL
)
```

table looks like

```
SLNO    COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3 SLNO2   COLUMN4 COLUMN5 COLUMN6 COLUMN7 COLUMN8 COLUMN9 COLUMN10    COLUMN11
10000   a   aa  ;   10000   aaa aaaa    aaaaa   aaaaaa  ;   aaaaa2  aaaaa12 aaaa22
10002   b   bb  ;   10002   bbb bbbb    bbbb    bbbbbb  ;   bbbbb2  bbbbb12 bbb22
10003   c   cc  ;   10003   ccc cccc    cccc    cccccc  ;   ccccc2  ccccc12 ccc22
```

I need to split each and every row in this table and the split should happen on columns 3 and 8( the ; is added artificially to have a separator)

Finally, the output should looks like:

```
Column  Column  Column  Column  Column  Column
10000   a   aa  ;       
10000   aaa aaaa    aaaaa   aaaaaa  ;
aaaaa2  aaaaa12 aaaa22          
10001   b   bb  ;       
10001   bbb bbbb    bbbb    bbbbbb  ;
bbbbb2  bbbbb12 bbb22           
10001   c   cc  ;       
10001   ccc cccc    cccc    cccccc  ;
ccccc2  ccccc12 ccc22
```

The semicolons are added to have a separator and a mark where the row should be split. 
Any ideas?

Comment: column 3 and 8 is static ?

Comment: yes, they are static

Answer (score 0):

```
select slno c1, column1 c2, column2 c3, ';' c4, null c5, null c6 from table
union all
select column4 c1, column5 c2, column6 c3, column7 c4, column8 c5, ';' c6 from table
union all
select column9 c1, column10 c2, column11 c3, ';' c4, null c5, null c6 from table;
```

If you need this ordered you can have:

```
select c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6 from
(    select slno c1, column1 c2, column2 c3, ';' c4, null c5, null c6, rowid r from table
    union all
    select column4 c1, column5 c2, column6 c3, column7 c4, column8 c5, ';' c6, rowid r from table
    union all
    select column9 c1, column10 c2, column11 c3, ';' c4, null c5, null c6, rowid r from table)
order by r
```

**EDIT**

If this is just for export I would go for:

```
select slno  || ',' ||  column1  || ',' || column2  || ',' ||  ';' linerow from table
union all
select column4 || ',' || column5 || ',' || column6  || ',' ||  column7 c4 || ',' ||  column8 c5 || ',' ||  ';' linerow from table
union all
select column9  || ',' ||  column10  || ',' ||  column11  || ',' ||  ';' linerow from table;
```

Comment: it does not an answer

Comment: Is it possible to avoid the null values? This will be exported in a CSV later and those null will appear

Comment: @ZacksiZacksiev nulls are there due to consistency. One query has 5-6 columns others 3-4. If you want to avoid nulls you can export separatel;y subqueries that are 3 columns and 5 columns.

Comment: @ZacksiZacksiev what more it make no sense to have single CSV file with different number of columns in differen rows. So either export it as a 3 separate files or leave there null columns

Comment: @Kacper thanks for the answers. In fact what would be exported is a file that would be import in a system. The format is predefined and I cannot play with the number of columns therefore nulls would ruin the import as the type of row is specified. For the moment I have all of that with adding CRLF (chr(13)||chr(10) ) instead of semicolon but the split is done during the export and not within the select.

Comment: @ZacksiZacksiev If that's just fopr export I would select it as a single value for line as in edited answer.